# Thread inside of onClick in Android Studio

Tags: android, multithreading

In Android Studio I need to send several frames to the outside when clicking on a button, each frame must be sent every 200ms for this I am using a thread, the first time the button is clicked everything runs fine but after pressing the button for the second time the application crashes, which is what I'm doing wrong?

Here mi code:

```
public class TerminalFragment extends Fragment implements ServiceConnection, SerialListener {
.
.
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_terminal, container, false);
.
.
myBotonSend = view.findViewById(R.id.bt_SendButton);
.
.
myBotonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
     mySendTramaThread.start();
    }
  });

  return view;
}
```

Here my Thread:

```
Thread mySendTramaThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        counterReintentos =5;
        flagReceiver =false;
        stringvalorOfNroTrama =Integer.toString(nroTrama +1);
        while((!flagReceiver)  && (counterReintentos != 0) ){
            try {
                bufferSendTrama = "{\"f\":\"" + stringvalorOfNroTrama + "\"}";
                Log.e("DEBUGTX-->", bufferSendTrama);
                send(bufferSendTrama.toString());
                counterReintentos--;
                Log.e("DEBUG-->", "CounterReintentos = " + counterReintentos);
                Thread.sleep(2000); //Delay
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("DEBUG_ERROR", "exception", e);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < nroTrama; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200); //Delay
                bufferSendTrama = myBuffer.substring((20 * i), (i * 20 + 20));
                Log.e("DEBUGTX-->", bufferSendTrama);
                send(bufferSendTrama.toString());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Log.e("DEBUG_ERROR", "exception", e);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

And here the Log Error

```
    --------- beginning of crash
2021-06-24 20:21:58.103 4803-4803/com.wsr.blespotx E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.wsr.blespotx, PID: 4803
java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:868)
    at com.wsr.blespotx.TerminalFragment$4.onClick(TerminalFragment.java:275)     HERE THE ERRO
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7870)
    at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14970)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7839)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:886)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29363)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
```

Comment: Try removing your `try catch` statements outside of the loops instead and calling `mySendTramaThread.interrupt()` first in `onClick()`.

Comment: Darkman, I have already tried to eliminate the try catch but I can't because I need the 200ms delays if I delete them I get error

Comment: I didn't mean to remove them completely; instead put them outside of your loops. `try { for(...) {} catch(...) {}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example.

```java
public class TerminalFragment extends Fragment implements ServiceConnection, SerialListener
{
    public static final class MyThread implements Runnable
    {
        private final Thread thread;
        private int state = 0;

        public final MyThread() {
            thread = new Thread(this);
            thread.start();
        }
        //Reminder :: Never call this method directly.
        @Override
        public final void run() {
            while(state < 2) {
                try {
                    synchronized(this) {
                        while(state == 0) this.wait();
                    }
                    //<!-- START BLOCK -->

                   //Do something here...
                   for(int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                       System.out.printf("%04d%n", i);
                           Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }

                    //<!-- END BLOCK -->
                } catch(final InterruptedException e) {}
            }
        }

        private final synchronized boolean resume() {
            if(state == 0) {
                state = 1;
                this.notify();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        private final void suspend() {
            if(state == 1) {
                state = 0;
                thread.interrupt();
            }
        }

        //Interrupt the thread if its currently waiting or sleeping.
        private final void stop() { //Only once.
            state = 3;
            thread.interrupt();
        }
    }

    private MyThread mySendTramaThread; //Global variable

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...
        mySendTramaThread = new MyThread();
        myBotonSend = view.findViewById(R.id.bt_SendButton);

        myBotonSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mySendTramaThread.suspend();
                final boolean resumable = mySendTramaThread.resume();
                if(!resumable) {
                    Log.e("DEBUG: ", "[ERROR] Unable to resume the thread!");
                }
            }
        });
        ...
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        mySendTramaThread.stop();
        mySendTramaThread = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if(mySendTramaThread != null) {
            mySendTramaThread.stop();
            mySendTramaThread = null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `Darkman`, nothing changes, I keep getting the same error

Comment: @w1ll Take a look at my example. That's all I can help.

Comment: `Darkman`, With your code I already managed to kill and start the thread in fragment, but now I have conflict with the action `onBackPressed ()`, if I comment your code I can use the onBackPressed () but when it is active it does not

Comment: Huh, I dont think that the thread's gonna be a problem. Have you called `super.onBackPressed()` in your `onBackPressed()`?

Comment: `Darkman`, Yes, I have also called `onBackPressed()`, but I still have this error:`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke direct method 'void com.wsr.msgspotx.TerminalFragment$MyThread.stop()'` on a null object

Comment: Ahhh, my bad. I've edited my answer to reflect that. Previously, I've made the `mySendTramaThread` as a local to `onCreateView()` but now as a global to the  whole class. Also I've changed some `private`s to `public`s for the thread for flexibility and added extra `onDestroy()` to kill the thread for sure.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to start an already started thread.

You haven't posted all of your code, but it's clear that your thread has been initialized somewhere else and referenced by mySendTramaThread.

So the first time your onClick fires, your thread is started.  And the second time your onClick fires, you try to start it again.

This is what is causing the IllegalThreadStateException.

You could check to see whether your thread is started first before calling start by calling `isAlive()`.

Comment: Michal, my  thread is started inside of .setOnClickListener